# Ktor - Deployment || Hosting Compatibility ( Server & Database Types )

Tags: mysql, hosting, vps, shared-hosting, ktor

I am an Android developer and interested in getting familiar with REST APIs development. I have experience with the Kotlin language as it is recommended for Android development. Hence I decided to develop the REST APIs using Kotlin only. In that case I have only 1 option which is Ktor. But before starting the development I want to know about the Ktor support or compatibility with hosting platforms available in the market.

**Does it support it?**

**Ktor Rest APIs - Hosting on Server Types:**

- Shared Server    : ??
- VPS Server   : ??
- AWS      : ??
- Google Cloud : ??

**Ktor Database Connetions :**

- MySQL : ??
- PostgreSQL    : ??
- MongoDB   : ??

***It would be more helpful if you can share some references to cover above topics.***

Might be it would be very silly question for you but lack of knowledge about backend development i need answers of above queries.

Thanks & looking forward to your response.

Comment: Since the Ktor server application can be launched on JVM, you can deploy the application anywhere where the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is installed. You can use any of those database management systems with Ktor because Ktor doesn't impose constraints on the persistence technologies used in the project.